# Crear un constructor a partir de un método que devuelva una lista de listas Python

Tags: python, poo, lista, csv

Tengo este método estático que lee un archivo CSV desde el parámetro "path" y devuelve una lista con todos sus elementos.

En este caso, el archivo tiene atributos como pista, artista, género, etc. Tengo que crear el constructor para trabajar con él.

```
@staticmethod
    def load_songs(path):
        songs = []
        
        with open(path) as f:
            for section in f:
                song_info = [(data) for data in section.strip().split(',')]
                songs.append(song_info)
                
        return songs
```

Por el momento tengo el constructor vacio.

```
def __init__(self, track, artist, genre, ...):
```

Ejemplo que saca la lista:

```
[['China', 'Anuel AA', 'reggaeton flow', '105', '81', '79', '302'], ['Beautiful People (feat. Khalid)', 'Ed Sheeran', 'pop', '93', '65', '64', '198']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada: no leas un archivo .csv "a mano", parece simple pero hay muchos detalles que pueden fallar (por ejemplo ¿qué pasa si el título contiene una coma?). La librería estándar incluye el módulo [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

El caso más simple sería que el archivo tenga siempre las mismas columnas en el mismo orden conocido. Digamos que son tres columnas: track, artist, genre. Entonces en cada iteración sobre el csv.reader obtenemos una lista con `[track, artist, genre]` cada vez. Si definimos el constructor de la clase Song con esos mismos argumentos en ese mismo orden, todo es más simple. La magia está en esta línea:

```
song = Song(*row)
```

En una llamada a función, el * indica que esa variable se usará para completar los parámetros posicionales en el orden en que están.

```python
import os
import csv


class Song:
    def __init__(self, track, artist, genre):
        self.track = track
        self.artist = artist
        self.genre = genre

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Song(track={!r}, artist={!r}, genre={!r})'.format(self.track, self.artist, self.genre)


class Songs(list):
    @classmethod
    def load_songs(cls, path):
        songs = cls()
        with open(path, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                song = Song(*row)
                songs.append(song)
        return songs


# crear el archivo de test, si no existe
if not os.path.isfile('test.csv'):
    with open('test.csv','wt') as f:
        f.write("""\
China,Anuel AA,reggaeton flow
Beautiful People (feat. Khalid),Ed Sheeran,pop
""")
songs = Songs.load_songs('test.csv')
print(songs)
```

Aceptar columnas variables no es tan complicado, si los nombres son conocidos y solo cambia el orden. La primera linea del archivo debe tener los nombres de columna (como es usual):

```
artist,track,genre
Anuel AA,China,reggaeton flow
Ed Sheeran,Beautiful People (feat. Khalid),pop
```

Y usamos un `csv.DictReader`[2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), que devuelve un diccionario por cada línea `{'artist':'Anuel AA', 'track':'China', genre:'reggaeton flow'}` y se lo pasamos al constructor con esta magia:

```
song = Song(**row)
```

**row significa que los ítems de ese diccionario se asignan a los parámetros por nombre de la función, respetando sus nombres.

```python
    @classmethod
    def load_songs_varnames(cls, path):
        songs = cls()
        with open(path, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for row in reader:
                song = Song(**row)
                songs.append(song)
        return songs
```